# Bigquery cron job does not work when user is not logged in to Google Cloud shell

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My cron job runs python code from App Engine on a scheduled time, but works only when I am logged in to the Google Cloud shell. When I quit Google Cloud shell, the cron job is still executed, but the python code takes no effect in BigQuery, where it should write data (as it does when I am logged in).

My guess it has something to do with authentication, but due to the docs, it should "just work" with my credentials. 
http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/auth.html

Any guesses what to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

This won't work in Google Cloud Shell.  Cloud Shell is not meant for non-interactive use and the VM is reclaimed soon after you log out or a period of inactivity. See https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits for more information.

Comment: It is not meant to work in Google Cloud Shell -> there is just relation that if the Google Cloud Shell is opened and cron job is executed, it executes correctly. But if I leave Cloud Shell (for example I log out), the cron job is executed, but it fails (code run takes no effect in BigQuery).

Comment: The cron job can't execute for long in Cloud Shell after you log out, because the VM is reclaimed after a period inactivity, but it will continue to work for a little while until that happens.

Comment: Clarification: you might be _observing_ that a cron job executes in Cloud Shell after you log out, but that won't happen for long because the VM is reclaimed after a period inactivity.  I suspect the reason your cron job stops working immediately after you log out is that your credentials for bq are propagated into Cloud Shell from the web browser terminal, and once you log it cannot happen.  You need to provide credentials to bq in a different way.  Check out the various credential_file options in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference.